# Effect of `explicit` on static upcasting

Tags: c++

May an instance of a derived class be implicitly converted to an instance of its base class, when the only candidate constructor in the base class is marked `explicit`?

---

I ran this:

```
struct Base {
   Base() {}
   explicit Base(Base const& b) {}
};

struct Derived : Base {};

int main() {
   Derived d;
   Base b = d;
}
```

And got this:

> error: no matching function for call to 'Base::Base(Derived&)'

Then I ran this:

```
struct Base {
   Base() {}
   Base(Base const& b) {}
};

struct Derived : Base {};

int main() {
   Derived d;
   Base b = d;
}
```

And got no errors.

But I'm not entirely convinced that this test succeeds due to `explicit`ness rather than ctor synthesis. In particular, I didn't think that `explicit` cared about the type of arguments, but that it would force me to write `Base b = static_cast<Base>(d)` ... which I'm not doing in either case.

Comment: There's always the possibility that your compiler isn't fully standards-compliant. I doubt that's the case here, but can't rule it out. That's why there's so much quoting of standards on SO.

Comment: @Mike: I appreciate that. I have leapt to full faith of my compiler for compliance when testing the above snippets, but they're so trivial that I think that's justified.

Comment: Well, practically speaking, what the compiler accepts is the only thing that matters, and standards are only valuable in as much as they're followed. But writing an SO answer from that point of view is a great way to get downvoted. There are a lot of questions, this one included, which I simply don't answer because I don't own a copy of the standard.

Comment: @Mike: I understand. I usually follow that myself. However, in this trivial case I don't feel that a standards quote is _required_. Of course, one would be the most authoritative answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not the conversion that fails.  Copy-initialization requires an accessible copy-constructor.

This also fails:

```
struct Base {
   Base() {}
   explicit Base(Base const& b) {}
};

int main() {
   Base d;
   Base b = d;
}
```

Comment: N3126 13.3.1.3: "When objects of class type are direct-initialized or copy-initialized from an expression of the same or a derived class type, overload resolution selects the constructor. ... For copy-initialization, the candidate functions are all the converting constructors of that class."  "converting constructor" is a C++0x term roughly meaning non-`explicit`.  I don't have C++03 with me now, but I bet its version of that paragraph is similar.

Comment: OK. So, by extension if nothing else, "no"?

Comment: Actually I think that the conversion _does_ fail, and your presented case does not rule that out; it merely demonstrates that eliminating the conversion doesn't fundamentally change the issue. The "conversion from `Base` to `Base`" (in quotes for a reason) is no better off than the conversion from `Derived` to `Base`. I can't think of a way in which either "conversion" may succeed.

Comment: @Tomalak but there is no conversion to speak of since `T t = u;` is already invalid (no non-explicit/converting constructor); if the construct were valid *then* overload resolution and conversions would take place, and there could be an invalid conversion.

Comment: @Luc: Hmm, I see! Does the standard make a distinction, then, between "no non-explicit converting constructor" and "no candidate non-explicit converting constructor [potentially after conversions]"?

Comment: @Tomalak I think this would be better suited as a chat discussion. (i.e. I need to ask you for details on what you're asking and the answer could be long.)

Comment: I only just noticed @aschepler's comment, which satisfies me.

Answer (score 1):

In hindsight, it seems clear.

The elements at play here are:

- The only would-be-synthesised candidate constructor is `Base(Base const&)`, and I don't provide a constructor `Base(Derived const&)`.
- Said constructor is `explicit`, but I provide no explicit conversion.

So, the answer is "no".

Comment: `Base(Derived const&)` would come into play if you wrote `Base b(d);`, which is *direct initialization*.  The case you asked about is *copy-initialization* and requires an accessible implicit copy constructor, even if a converting constructor also existed and was accessible and implicit.

Comment: @Ben: I don't understand the distinction. Either one requires an accessible implicit copy constructor (as long as an `Derived::operator Base` isn't in existence, I suppose...?). I suppose I'm using the term "copy constructor" to include what I just realised you meant by "converting constructor". I have changed all my utterings of "copy constructor" to just "constructor". Is this more clear?

Comment: @Tomalek: A copy constructor has the signature `T::T(T&)` or `T::T(const T&)` only.  If you provided a constructor `implicit Base::Base(const T&)` (which is NOT a copy constructor) then `Base b(d);` would succeed, while `Base b = d;` would still fail if `T` were unrelated.  Subclasses are a special case, where `Base b = d;` also succeeds.

Comment: @Ben: Is `implicit` really a keyword?

Answer (score -1):

This:

```
int main() {
   Derived d;
   Base b = d;
}
```

is not upcasting. That is creating a *new object*, called `b`, which contains a *copy* of the value of `d`. In order to have upcasting, you must be using polymorphic values (references or pointers). Upcasting would therefore be:

```
int main() {
   Derived d;
   Base &b = d;
}
```

The variable `b` contains a reference to the `Base` part of `d`. If `Base` had some public member `int baseValue;`, then `b.baseValue` refers to the exact same data as `d.baseValue`. For example:

```
int main() {
   Derived d;
   Base &b = d;
   d.baseValue = 10;
   cout << b.baseValue << endl;
}
```

This will write `10`. If `b` weren't a reference, but a regular object, it would have copied the (initialized) value from `d` before `d`'s value was changed. And therefore changing one would not change the other.

The purpose of the `explicit` keyword is to prevent syntax like `Base b = d` from working. If you make a constructor `explicit`, you are saying, "I don't want the compiler to ever implicitly call this copy constructor. If the user is to use it, then they *must* explicitly say so." If you want implicit conversion of types, then you must say so.

Comment: @Tomalak: I don't think "casting" is defined in the standard at all.  There are cast operators and cast notation, but those are syntactical, not semantic.

Comment: It's an upcast followed by a copy (slicing occurs).

Comment: Upcasting is converting a `Derived` instance to a `Base` instance, which must occur here. Your `Base& b = d` doesn't actually convert the object; indeed, that's how polymorphism _works_.

Comment: 'polymorphic' means there are virtual functions. I don't think that's what you mean there. And doesn't `Base b = d;` involve an implicit reference conversion in order to invoke the Base copy constructor?

Comment: @Tomalak: "Upcasting is converting a Derived instance to a Base instance, which must occur here." I don't understand what you mean. A Derived instance will _always_ be a Derived instance, even if you pretend it was a Base instance (with a cast, as I did with the Base&). What you're doing is copy initialization of a _new object_, which is different from the original. That's not casting.

Comment: @Nicol: I know what polymorphism is, I know what references are, and I know what `explicit` means. If creating a new object of type `T1` from an object of type `T2` is not conversion (casting if the conversion is explicit; in this case I'm talking about _implicit_ conversions in fact), then I don't know what is...

Comment: @Tomalak: "I know what polymorphism is, I know what references are, and I know what explicit means." Then what are you asking for? You made a constructor explicit and then you tried to invoke it implicitly. The compiler said no, exactly as you told it to.

Comment: Upcasting is conversion of `Derived*` or `Derived&` to `Base*` or `Base&` (with possible *cv-modifiers*).  And yes, it enables polymorphism.  Virtual functions are also needed to actually get polymorphic, but this is the principle behind it.

Comment: You have no cast in `Base& b = d;`. You don't even have a _conversion_ of the original object `d`. You *are* converting references, but that's not what this question is about.

Comment: @Tomalek: Creating a new object of type `T1` from an object of type `T2` IS *conversion*.  But you called it *upcasting*.  An *upcast* is creation of a base-typed pointer or reference.  To confuse matters, the conversion consists of an upcast followed by a copy, but still, **saying the conversion is an upcast is incorrect**.

Comment: @Tomalak: This seems to be a semantics problem. To me, "casting" is "pretend X is a Y." "Conversion" is "_transform_ X into a Y" or "build an X from a Y". For me, these are two separate operations, even though there are certain things that are called "casts" (`static_cast<float>(someInteger)`) that are actually conversions. `Base(d)` is not a cast; it is the construction of a new object that has some part of the value of `d`.

Comment: @Nicol: I don't see a semantics problem. "Casting" is well-defined in the standard, and "pretending" has absolutely nothing to do with it. A cast is an explicit conversion, and your chosen definitions are at odds with the C++ standard in that regard.